# PyCharm Docker Deployment "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: plugins, docker, pycharm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've set up the Docker Deployment plugin on PyCharm, however, on hitting play, the Deploy log shows a failure with:

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'environments/dev/requirements.txt'
```

I assume that this has something to do with the docker build context that is part of the Docker Deployment plugin. I've confirmed that there is in fact a requirements.txt file in the environments/dev/ directory inside the root of my PyCharm project. Does anyone know how to specify the docker build context/path in PyCharm or the Docker Deployment plugin?

**UPDATE:**

By adding `RUN ls -l` to the Dockerfile, I was able to deduce that the plugin is running from the same directory as the Dockerfile. Still looking for a way to specify the build path if it's at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution to this problem is to move the Dockerfile to the root directory of my PyCharm project so that when `ADD . /var/app` is run, it copies over the correct files. As I mentioned in the "UPDATE", the PyCharm plugin uses the directory the Dockerfile is run from as the build context/path.

Would still like to be able to specify the build path, but this may be the best solution given the limitations of the plugin.